Tailwindcss classes are not applying after build
Tailwindcss classes are not applying after build - This issue is resolved.

Seems like I did not check my code after building the library, it was a formatting issue that I was facing.

It seems like the extra spaces are present in the source code of the component in the library itself:
const buttonVariants = cva(
  "inline-flex items-center justify-center whitespace-nowrap rounded-md text-sm font - medium transition - colors focus - visible: outline - none focus - visible: ring - 1 focus - visible: ring - ring disabled: pointer - events - none disabled: opacity - 50",
  {

Consider repairing the extraneous spaces in the source code of the library by removing the spaces like:
const buttonVariants = cva(
  "inline-flex items-center justify-center whitespace-nowrap rounded-md text-sm font-medium transition-colors focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-1 focus-visible:ring-ring disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50",
  {

